# Accept for input type validation issue

Tags: html, laravel, file, validation, input

Hello I have added accept in file input type and when i upload png image it show error `Please enter a value with a valid extension.` searched a lot and tried different ways but couldn't figure out.

Below is the code for file type.

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept=".jpg, .png,.jpeg" id="file" class="custom-file-input" />
```

When i upload `png` image then only issue occurs with message `Please enter a value with a valid extension.`

In controller below is the code for validation of image.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|max:4000',
            ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello i have resolved the issue and the problem was `space between accept types`

code with bug is as below

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept=".jpg, .png,.jpeg" id="file" class="custom-file-input" />
```

After resolving bug (in accept there is space after `.jpg, .png`) so removed it.

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg" id="file" class="custom-file-input" />
```

Comment: thanks. I initially used accept="image/*" and it keeps getting the error until i tried your solution

Answer (score 0):

You have not completed the requirements for the `mimetypes` rule:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-mimetypes

```
'image' => 'mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image|max:4000',
```

You should use the `mimes` rule as shown in the docs

```
'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png|max:4000',
```

Comment: Still getting error `Please enter a value with a valid extension.` no luck

Comment: It shows error message from `jquery.validate.min.js` js script

Comment: have a look at this: https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/1258 . Try `jzaefferer` suggestion of using the `extension` method

Answer (score 0):

Without the complete code, it won't be easy for anyone to tell you exactly what can be the error or problem.

I assume you are using a form to submit the file and you might have missed `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form tag.